# Roll up summary - contact to account

Tags: trigger

Thanks for your prompt reply...!!

Requirement : There is a custom field IsActive__c(checkbox) on Contact,list of contacts with checkbox is true - only those count should rollup on account field( no_of_active_contacts__c) a number field,  using trigger on Contact. Please help me in achieving this.

Comment: Can you elaborate ur requirement.. ? r u looking to achieve rollup kind of functionality using trigger ? If yes, what u want to populate on account ?

Comment: Hi Sindhu, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. Remember, the more (relevant) details you can give, the better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) here. It is a rigorous, well documented package that allows you to declaratively create rollup summaries for lookup relationships.